# Installing tensorflow on windows10 -python 3.6.1 (anaconda)

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I'm trying to install tensorflow onto my machine, but it's not working well.

I referred to the tensorflow homepage, and decided to install it with anaconda, on which I'm currently running my python.

So I did..

```
>conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5  #One of the posts on Stackoverflow 
                                        #told the other to put 'python=3.5' even when
                                        #installing on python3.6.x.. So I did as what's said
>activate tensorflow
(tensorflow)>pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow
```

But when I run the last line above, I get:

```
Collecting tensorflow
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
 No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

What should I do to resolve my problem?

By the way, my pip version is 9.0.1 / anaconda 4.3.30 / python 3.6.1

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow does have python 3.6 binaries uploaded to pypi.
you just need to run `pip install tensorflow` in an administrator terminal and that is it.
On windows, a common issue on windows with anaconda is, you almost always need a terminal with administrator privileges to install anything. So that may be causing issues for you.

URL to the latest windows python 3.6 pip package:
https://pypi.python.org/packages/76/7b/2048b4ecd88395ac16ab938e8675ffeda2acb60bc34f5ef63500eafafaf5/tensorflow-1.4.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl#md5=7bdc1e94f1cb772ae5851018dc23a62e

TensorFlow official installation documentation for windows:
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows

Comment: Well.. I AM installing with an administrator privilege. But I still get the same message :
 'Collecting tensorflow
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow'

Comment: How about without `conda create ....` command you are running, and then just `pip install tensorflow`?

Answer (score -1):

I think tensorflow is not yet available for python 3.6.

If you are using anaconda, you can try setting up a virtual environment with python 3.5.

https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands

You can try the test version for windows here,

pip install -i https://testpypi.python.org/pypi tensorflow

Or you could try installing tensorflow from a wheel file like this (although this didn't succeed for me) :

pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl